# Left and Top menu disappear after wake up

Tags: 14.04, menu

My Left and Top menu disappear after wake up.  my Laptops is IBM x41. Is the reason that the laptops is too old?   the ubuntu version is  14.04

Comment: Does rebooting help or not? If not, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary, up to a certain point of slowness, the older the laptop is, the more likely it is to be compatible with Ubuntu.

I'm not sure what is causing your difficulty, but I have a trick which should make it tolerable until such time as a solution is found.  I had a similar problem on a gateway and I discovered I could refresh the GUI desktop by pressing two key combinations in sequence.

First you press:

> ctrl - alt - F1

Then after the screen is black, you press:

> ctrl - alt - F7

In reality you are taking yourself to the full screen terminal, and then you are taking yourself back to the GUI, only this time everything works right, at least for me anyway.  Please let me know if this works for you.

PS:  Don't be surprised of a more knowledgeable user comes up with a way to refresh the  GUI in a slightly simpler, or perhaps more complicated way.